# Compiler warning about missing preprocessor symbol

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

**Background**

I have **C** project which has a configuration header file, for example:

```
// config.h
#define FEATURE_1_AVAILABLE      1
#define FEATURE_2_AVAILABLE      0
#define FEATURE_3_AVAILABLE      1
```

Modules use these flags to include/exclude features from build:

```
#include "config.h"
void foo(void) {
    ...
    #if FEATURE_1_AVAILABLE
    useFeature1();
    #endif
    ...
```

There are different versions of `config.h` for different builds.

**Problem**

`#include "config.h"` got accidentally removed, so feature wasn't active even when it was enabled in config.

Unfortunately `#if FEATURE_1_AVAILABLE` silently evaluates to `0` when it's not defined. So I need an error if it's not defined.

**Option 1**

I could add extra 'if defined' test on each condition.

```
#ifndef FEATURE_1_AVAILABLE
    #error No feature 1  
#elif FEATURE_1_AVAILABLE
    useFeature1();
#endif
```

Downside is that one feature flag may be tested in *many* different places in module, and adding multiple preprocessor lines is not going to make code prettier.

**Option 2**

Add single test at the beginning of the module:

```
#ifndef FEATURE_1_AVAILABLE
    #error  No feature 1  
#endif
```

But this can be lost/forgotten for the same reasons that `#include "config.h"` was.

**Option 3**

Define flags as macros:

```
#define FEATURE_1_AVAILABLE()      1
```

and use as:

```
#if FEATURE_1_AVAILABLE()
```

Unfortunaltely this will also fail silently, if you forget the parenthesis:

```
#if FEATURE_1_AVAILABLE
```

**Option X**

Is there a better option? Something that will give error message at compile time if symbol is not defined or is incorrectly written. And hopefully doesn't make code look unmaintainable preprocessor mess.

**Other things**

- Runtime checks are not possible. Disabled features must not be in the binary.
- Features must be defined in file. Defining them as global compiler options has other problems.
- This for embedded system. Some of these features require hardware to work, and testing is very time consuming. So having errors at compile time is preferred.

Comment: Find the person responsible for removing the include, and bop that person on the head. If you really need that specific header file included in all source files then all developers needs to know it. Also, things like this should have been automatically detected by the automated unit tests (you *do* have automated unit tests?) and would have been fixed before the program ever reaches the customer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But I don't want to hit myself :) It was removed by an accident. About the unit tests: As I wrote, testing some of these without hardware is impossible. So errors like these are cheaper to fix when detected at compile time.

Comment: @JimBalter At quick look it might be dupe. I'll look further and close this if it is.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution is to have the compiler warn you if a macro being evaluated is not defined.

With `gcc` for example there is the `-Wundef` option (not included in `-Wall`):

```
#if FEATURE_1_AVAILABLE
useFeature1();
#endif
```

this gives the warning (add `-Werror` to make it an error):

```
tst.c:6:9: warning: "FEATURE_1_AVAILABLE" is not defined [-Wundef]
     #if FEATURE_1_AVAILABLE
```

This option is also available with other compilers, e. g., `clang` and `icc`.

Comment: Note that this warning can give a lot of false positives, especially on systems which uses preprocessor macros for platform compatibility checks.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it's an option I usually use in my own programs (but only if I get zero warning from other third-party programs / libs)

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but in my case there would be a lot false positives from 3rd party libs.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is [being frowned upon](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?OneBigHeaderFile), but for smaller C projects there is nothing wrong with having *one* project-wide include file (say `myproject.h`) with all your `#include ..` directives (like `#include "config.h"`) , and then have *only* `#include "myproject.h` at the top of each source file.

Accidentally forgetting this single `#include` will usually break the compile immediately, so that won't happen unnoticed.

Alternatively, you could put one essential `#include` (say `#include assert.h`) in your `config.h` (and only there), again to annoy the compiler/linker when you forget to include it